# It is possible to run an entire script on the Linux side? If so, how, what and where to do that?

Tags: programming, sketch, arduino-yun, web

I am new to using Arduino Yun and I would like to know if it is possible to run an entire script on the Linux side. In my case the script should execute a HTTP request to a remote server, parse the subsequent HTTP response and return some value that then can be used in the Arduino sketch.

If it is possible, what I have to do? For example, how should I write and run script files? what programming language should I use? where I should put those script files on the Linux side?

Comment: Not a Yun expert but [shell commands seem easy on the Yun](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShellCommands). I don't know much about adding a script to it, so feel free to build off of this and post an answer.

Comment: Don't know anything about Yun but I'd look at the FileIO class to make a file and write your script into it. Then use Process class to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino Yun ships with python pre installed. You can copy python scripts from your pc to the yun with `scp` (or WinSCP or `putty`, if you're on windows). Once copied, just run it using Process from your sketch. As they are scripts, program name is `python` and the path to your script is its first argument (you can do that in a different way, but that would require some linux magic, which I suggest to postpone if you're new to it).

Other pre installed options include [lua](http://www.lua.org/) and bash. Other languages such as ruby, erlang and php are available as optional packages.

Comment: In which directory on Yun should I put my script files?

Comment: Wherever, but the sd card is the preferred choice, so you don't wear out the flash. If you have an sd card with an `arduino` folder, you should have it available at `/mnt/sd`